# Babel error: "Couldn't find preset 'latest' relative to directory" when preset was installed globally

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I installed Babel globally like this:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
npm install -g babel-preset-latest
```

I know it's not recommended to do it globally, but I prefer this way to keep my directory clean (no node_modules/ and no package.json)

Then I have a mainES6.js file written in ES6 that I want in ES5, so I do this:

```
babel mainES6.js -o mainES5.js --presets latest
```

And I get this message: `Error: Couldn't find preset "latest" relative to directory "/path/to/my/file/"`

How to make that work?

Comment: for those having some issue, is due the fact that now is been deprecated. The name of the module that integrate this funcionality is : npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

Answer (score 5):

This already has been mentioned in Babel GitHub Issues: [babel-cli and babel-node ignore global presets (installed with npm -g)](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2816). It seems that there's no way to make it work apart from installing it locally.